# Invoke Static Generic Method via delegate via Emit

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, static, reflection.emit

I try to create a deleagte to invoke a  static generic Method. But I got the error: Invalid code detected! nyone a idea what is wrong with my IL?

The FindStaticMethod Call in the Example Code is working and Returning a Method Info, with the given Type arguments!

```
 public delegate object GenericStaticInvoker(params object[] arguments);

 public static GenericStaticInvoker GenericMethodInvokerStaticMethod(Type type, string methodName, Type[] typeArguments, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo;
        ParameterInfo[] parameters;

        // find the method to be invoked
        FindStaticMethod(type, methodName, typeArguments, parameterTypes, out methodInfo, out parameters);

        string name = string.Format("__MethodInvoker_{0}_ON_{1}", methodInfo.Name, methodInfo.DeclaringType.Name);

        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod;
        dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(name, typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(object[]) }, methodInfo.DeclaringType);

        ILGenerator generator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

        // define local vars
        if (methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(void))
            generator.DeclareLocal(methodInfo.ReturnType);

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            // load paramters they are passed as an object array
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

            // load array element
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);

            // cast or unbox parameter as needed
            Type parameterType = parameters[i].ParameterType;
            if (parameterType.IsClass)
            {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, parameterType);
            }
            else
            {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, parameterType);
            }
        }

        // call method
        generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, null);

        // handle method return if needed
        if (methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(void))
        {
            // return null
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);                
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
        else
        {
            // box value if needed
            if (methodInfo.ReturnType.IsValueType)
            {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Box, methodInfo.ReturnType);
            }

            // store to the local var
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

            // load local and return
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }



        // return delegate
        return (GenericStaticInvoker)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(GenericStaticInvoker));
    }
```

Comment: I need this exact code, any chance you get update your question with the working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In an instance method, the "this" parameter can be loaded onto the evaluation stack by Ldarg_0 and then the "actual" parameters can be loaded with Ldarg_{x} (with x 1 through N).
- When you have a static method (also the case of any lambda, be it reflection.emitted or not) the "actual" parameters can be loaded with Ldarg_{x} (with x 0 through N-1).
- To wrap it all up for the general case: the "this" reference is a parameter in its own right.
  Its absence does not leave an empty slot onto the stack (the **ldarg.0** will and must be used for the first non-"this" parameter).

So in your particular case, you can't use **OpCodes.Ldarg_1** do load your *params object[] parameters* unique parameter:

```
// ...etc...
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
    // load paramters they are passed as an object array
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

    // ...etc...
```

You should use **OpCodes.Ldarg_0**:

```
// ...etc...
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
    // load paramters they are passed as an object array
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

    // ...etc...
```